# Getting a Sharepoint Calendar Feed

Tags: sharepoint

I was wondering if there is a way to get a feed (xml, or other format) for a sharepoint calendar.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can get an RSS feed for a view by clicking "Modify this view" and clicking the RSS icon. ([Reference](http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/Blogs/GetThePoint/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=94))

Answer (score 0):

If your target client is Outlook, you might have better luck with the Connect to Outlook functionality under the Calendar's Action menu.  See [information at this link.](http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/blogs/GetThePoint/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=73)